# Running Watir code in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, watir

Trying to run some Watir code as a Rake task that is giving me this error:

```
$ bundle exec rake update_market_rents:market_rents
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
(in C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/lib/tasks/update_market_rents.rake:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/310046998/sites/testpropinvest/vendor/bundle/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => update_market_rents:market_rents
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Code:

```
namespace :update_market_rents do
  desc "TODO"
  task market_rents: :environment do

    #watir code

    require 'watir-webdriver'
    Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

    browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff

    #blah blah more code

    browser.close

  end
end
```

If I run the Watir code from the command prompt using `$ ruby filename.rb`, I have no problems. For some reason, when I try to run it via the Rake command I get the above error.  I'm struggling to find what's happening given that I see the code work okay alone.

I've tried adding `require 'rubygems'` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux then run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

On Mac:

```
brew install node
```